# Simple app to show map doesn't work android

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am doing online coursera class on android, and there is a simple application that is supposed to take a string for a location and show a map of where it is. I imported the maplocation project in android studio from this site https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android/tree/master/Examples/MapLocation, ran on the emulator, entered the address provided in the video and clicked "Show map" but there is nothing.

Screenshot:

[image]

In the error log it says:

> 06-30 18:14:55.317 2151-2151/course.examples.maplocation
>   E/MapLocation: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity
>   found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=geo:0,0?q=washington+dc }

How do I resolve this? Why isn't an activity being started?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an emulator, I have a suspicion that your emulator does not have an app installed that can view the coordinates. Try running the app on actual device instead. The emulator usually does not have Google Play Services installed and thus you probably don't have the Google Maps app installed on the emulator either. i.e. There is no app on the emulator that can open that location data.

Comment: Thanks, i was able to run on my phone.  I was watching this video https://www.coursera.org/learn/android-programming/lecture/u9rOp/application-fundamentals-part-1 and in it he actually is show google map on his phone.. i wonder how to install google map on the emulator

Comment: Yeah, it's actually rather complicated but still possible. Its best to do all map related testing on a device.